# If I create a file in Codebehind where does the physical file acually exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, io

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\CallInformation.txt", "Some data");
    }
```

is CallInformation.txt on the Server? Or the client? If it's the server, other than specifying a computer name (@"\Workstation\c$\CallInformation.txt") how can I get it to save the file client side?

Comment: It would be dangerous if the server was able to put files on the clients computer... Web browsing wouldn't be safe at all.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly. It's amazing that as a developer I think about how things could be done a specific way.. When really if I stopped and thought about it as an end-user it's instantly clear that anyone in their right mind would NOT allow this to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's on the server.   The code behind executes in the context of the web server.

To get a file to download, there are a few ways.  One way is to do something [along these lines](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/May/21/Downloading-a-File-with-a-Save-As-Dialog-in-ASPNET):

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=SailBig.jpg");
Response.TransmitFile( Server.MapPath("~/images/sailbig.jpg") );
Response.End();
```

Comment: This is what I expected, if you throw out an idea on how to get it client side other than my methodology you'll get that awesome green check mark.

Comment: Awesome RQDQ, will this cause an automatic transmit or does it require the user take action? I really need to write a file client side automatically.

Comment: This will depend on the browser (and the user settings)... The newer versions of IE tend to prompt by default.  Other browsers (e.g. Chrome) will download automatically to a default directory.  You won't be able to control where the file gets saved on the client.

Answer (score 5):

It is built on the server.  It would be a major security vulnerability if you could create a file on a client without them physically accepting it. You could always send the data to them as a stream and allow them to choose where to save it.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly. It's amazing that as a developer I think about how things could be done a specific way.. When really if I stopped and thought about it as an end-user it's instantly clear that anyone in their right mind would NOT allow this to happen. Thank you for your help.

Comment: My pleasure.  I rely on this site quite often, so when I can help out it is is joy. If you figure a way to control where the file gets saved let me know. I'd love to see how it would be accomplished. Also if I were you I would take the code from RQDQ and wrap it in a utility method so that you can reuse it as sending files to the client is something that I need to do quite frequently.

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing a web application, you should understand that the code runs on the server.
So the file is saved on the server.

To send it to the client, you have to write the contents of the file to the response stream.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I do in-fact understand that the code runs on the server, but it can all be quite confusing for a non-veteran developer how you can set a client pages label control content from serverside code. So to say the least the deduction about how it all works can be.... fuzzy.

Answer (score 1):

The file would be create on the server. To write it locally, you would need a client framework other than just the W3C DOM compliant browser, such as Silverlight and (maybe) Flash - and even then the user would be prompted to allow it to happen.

Here's a post that explains how it can be done:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/read-and-write-file-to-local-file-system-in-silverlight-4/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Very nice article and very informative, thank you. However we are not running out of browser. also unfortunately it has to be automatic. :'(